# How to change displayed data the best way in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to change displayed data in Flutter? I wrote a function changeDataForTest (only a function for testing the event), which should change the data displayed in Text.
But if I click on this, it isn't changed. The value of the displayed string only changes, if i add (context as Element).reassemble(); after calling the method. Is this the normal way to go, or is there a smoother way to solve my problem?

```
dynamic changeDataForTest(neuerWert) {
    this.data = neuerWert;
  }



Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            this.data + this.wiegehts,
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          textColor: Color(0xFF6200EE),
          onPressed: () {
            changeDataForTest('neuerWert');
            (context as Element).reassemble();
          },
        )
      ],
      
    )
```

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: use setState(), for statefulWidget

Comment: FlatButton says "This class is obsolete, please use TextButton instead.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using only a small widget, you could use a `StatefulWidget` using the method:

```
setState(() {
 // change your variable
})
```

If your widget is complex and has lots of different possible variables, I'll not recommend using `setState` as this method calls the `build` method every time is being used.

One simple and fast option, is to use `ValueNotifier`:

```
final myVariable = ValueNotifier(false); // where you can replace 'false' with any Object
```

and then, using it this way:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
   valueListenable: myVariable,
   builder: (context, value, child) {
      return Text(value); // or any other use of Widgets
   },
);

myVariable.value = true; // if you're looking for to change the current value
```

finally, if you logic is truly complex and you need to scale, I'll recommend to use a StateManagement library like:

- Provider
- Riverpod
- BloC
- Others

You can find those libraries and examples over: **https://pub.dev**